# Не создается база данных в entity framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Что может быть причиной данной ошибки?

```
 public class MyModel : DbContext
    {

        public MyModel()
            : base("name=MyModel")
        {
        }

         public virtual DbSet<Person> PersonsInfo { get; set; }
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public int A { get; set; }
        public string B { get; set; }
    }


class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyModel db = new MyModel();
            var list=db.PersonsInfo.ToList();
        }
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В сообщении все написано: "PersonsInfo is based on type Person that has no keys defined" - PersonInfo основан на типе Person у которого не определен первичный ключ.

Когда вы работаете с EF вы должны учитывать следующее: при именовании свойств у классов вы либо следуете, т.н. соглашениям (если свойство названо `Id` и имеет числовой тип, то это будет ключевое поле), либо используете аннотации в виде атрибутов `[Key]`, либо ручками с помощью Fluent API описываете поля и их тип `modelBuilder.Entity<Person>(entity => { entity.HasKey(e => e.A);});`.

Потому надо сделать так

```
public class Person
{
    [Key]
    public int A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: В чем может быть причина того,что не определяет атрибут key?

Comment: А почему вы решили, что не определяет? Ошибка та же возникает что-ли?

Comment: Просто цвет серый и красным подчеркивает

Comment: @Nikita установите курсор на подчеркивание, нажмите `Ctrl` и `.` и установите нужный `using`. А вообще, зайдите [сюда](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/netcore/new-db-sqlite) и пройдете урок самостоятельно.

Answer (score 3):

Для таблицы должен быть задан ключ, EntityFramework не работает с таблицами без ключа.

Ключ может быть задан через атрибут ключа `[Key]`, либо через FluentApi

```
public class Person
{
    [Key] // ключ задан через атрибут
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
}
```

Поле `Id` является ключём.

В данном случае `[Key]` можно не писать так как EF `int` поле с именем `Id` иди `ClassNameId` автоматически считает ключём.